# How to pass a Func<> property/method to a NancyFx Get() method?

Tags: c#, lambda, nancy, func

The NancyFx (2.x) `NancyModule.Get()` method is defined as:

```
public virtual void Get(string path, Func<dynamic, object> action, [Func<NancyContext, bool> condition = null], [string name = null]);
```

The normal usage is:

```
public class MyModule
{
    public MyModule() 
    {
        this.Get("/", parameters => {
            this.RequestHandler = new RequestHandler();

            return this.RequestHandler.HandleRequest("/", parameters, someOtherInfo);
        });
    }
}
```

I want to define the second parameter as a property, so that I can use for several paths like this:

```
public class MyModule
{
    Func<dynamic, object> indexHandler = parameters => {
        // Error: Keyword "this" is not available in this context
        this.RequestHandler = new RequestHandler();

        // Error: Keyword "this" is not available in this context
        return this.RequestHandler.HandleRequest("/", parameters, someOtherInfo);
    };

    public MyModule() 
    {
        this.Get("/", indexHandler);
        this.Get("/index", indexHandler);
    }
}
```

If I do this it works:

```
public class MyModule
{
    public MyModule() 
    {
        Func<dynamic, object> indexHandler = parameters => {
            this.RequestHandler = new RequestHandler();

            return this.RequestHandler.HandleRequest("/", parameters, someOtherInfo);
        };

        this.Get("/", indexHandler);
        this.Get("/index", indexHandler);
    }
}
```

But I don't want to define it in the constructor. What am I doing wrong? Is there any other way to do this?

## MVCE

**Dependancy Package:** Nancy (Version: 2.0.0-clinteastwood)

```
using Nancy;
using Nancy.Responses.Negotiation;

namespace MyNamespace
{
    public class MyModule : NancyModule
    {
        private RequestHandler RequestHandler;
        private object IndexHandler(dynamic parameters)
        {
            this.RequestHandler = new RequestHandler();
            var someOtherInfo = "";
            return this.RequestHandler.HandleRequest("/", parameters, someOtherInfo);
        }

        public MyModule()
        {
            this.Get("/", IndexHandler);
            this.Get("/index", IndexHandler);

            this.Get("/home", parameters => {
                return this.Negotiate.WithView("myview.html");
            });
        }
    }

    public class RequestHandler
    {
        public Negotiator HandleRequest(string path, dynamic parameters, string someOtherInfo)
        {
            return new Negotiator(new NancyContext());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @john-wu I'm not asking why I can't us "this" in the property. I'm asking for a way to define the function somewhere other than constructor and hence it is not the same as the question you have marked. Please read my question again.

Comment: `indexHandler ` is a field of `MyModule`, is it not?.

Comment: @JohnWu Yes. In the 2nd piece of code I posted. But what is my question? Is there a better way of defining it other than the constructor. Doesn't have to be as a field or a property. Look at the answer below. Does this resemble the answer in the question you have marked? Again, please read my question and try to understand it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Andrew's answer is valid and should've been sufficient but apparently (in your MVCE) that method definition doesn't exist.

Here's the correct definition (at least the one VS wants):

```
public virtual void Get(string path, Func<object, Task<object>> action, Func<NancyContext, bool> condition = null, string name = null)
```

Luckly your `HandleRequest` is awaitable so you only need to edit the return type.
Here's the correct definition:

```
private Task<object> IndexHandler(dynamic parameters)
{
    this.RequestHandler = new RequestHandler();
    var someOtherInfo = "";
    return this.RequestHandler.HandleRequest("/", parameters, someOtherInfo);
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 4):

This should work:

```
public class MyModule
{
    public MyModule() 
    {
       this.Get("/", IndexHandler);
       this.Get("/index", IndexHandler);
    }

    private object IndexHandler(dynamic parameters) {
        this.RequestHandler = new RequestHandler();
        return this.RequestHandler.HandleRequest("/", parameters, someOtherInfo);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think your parameter declaration is vaild C#. Otherwise correct answer.

Comment: Looks good but I get the following error where I pass this to the `Get()` method: `'dynamic MyModule.IndexHandler(object)' has the wrong return type`. Any idea?

Comment: I edited your answer @Andrew, the `Func<dynamic, object>` means it takes a dynamic parameter and returns an object.

Comment: @Haytam Thanks!

Comment: @Haytam I still get the same error `'object MyModule.IndexHandler(dynamic)' has the wrong return type`. Somehow I find this strange.

Comment: @NeilPatrao What does `this.RequestHandler.HandleRequest` return?

Comment: It returns a Negotiator object

Comment: Weird, the code works when I try it (without NancyFx)

Comment: @Haytam I've added an MVCE

Comment: @NeilPatrao Got it, indeed the error is present, I'll try to solve it and get back to you!